# locked screen audio controls ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm new to iOS and I'm trying to build an app using objective-c. The issue I'm having is that I can't get audio controls to display when the screen is locked.

I'm playing audio using AVPlayer.

In viewDidLoad I'm calling this method

```
- (void)screenLocked{

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self

selector:@selector(appDidEnterBackground:)

name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                           object:nil];
}
```

and that method calls this one

```
  - (void)appDidEnterBackground:(NSNotification *)notification {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

    MPRemoteCommandCenter *remoteCommandCenter = [MPRemoteCommandCenter 
    sharedCommandCenter];
    [[remoteCommandCenter playCommand] addTarget:self 
    action:@selector(test)];
    [[remoteCommandCenter skipForwardCommand] addTarget:self 
    action:@selector(test)];
    [[remoteCommandCenter skipBackwardCommand] addTarget:self 
    action:@selector(test)];
    [[remoteCommandCenter togglePlayPauseCommand] addTarget:self 
    action:@selector(test)];
    [[remoteCommandCenter pauseCommand] addTarget:self 
    action:@selector(test)];
}

- (void)test{
    NSLog(@"Logging");
}
```

When I run the app in the simulator and lock the screen to my dismay no controls appear. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the issue was my app wasn't configured to play audio in the background. I didn't realize that because in the simulator my app was playing music in the background just fine. However, when I ran my app on my actual phone it didn't play when the screen was locked.

So I had to enable background audio under the capabilities tab of my project and add this code in viewDidLoad

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
```

Also, audio controls don't seem to appear on my simulator at all.

Comment: As of Xcode 9b3 backgrounded processes should be suspended in the Simulator which should pause audio playback.